# if else one liner in python

Tags: python, if-statement, one-liner

```
a=0
b=0
s="1110000"
for i in range(len(s)):
   if s[i]=='1':
      a+=1
   else:
      b+=1
```

this if else I need to write in one line.
I tried below way it is not working.

```
a+=1 if if s[i]=='1' else b+=1
```

PLease help me on this

Comment: Not every if/else statement can be written as one line; and there is no reason it should.

Comment: @MohammadAliNematollahi No, it still wouldn't work.

Comment: "I need to write in one line" -- what is the nature of the need? Is this a homework requirement that you are stuck with, or is it simply a desired outcome?

Comment: I voted to close this question because the stated problem is a "need" to do things differently and I cannot reproduce that problem.

Comment: It looks like you could use the count method to achieve your goal : s.count('1') will give you a and len(s) - s.count('1) will give you b

Comment: To implement what @Francois has suggested, you can do it in one line without either if or for using `b = len(s) - (a := s.count('1'))` (Python 3.8 or above). Doesn't help you if you need to use if, as you state, but it is definitely faster than a loop.

Answer (score 3):

`if ... else` when used as a ternary operator, is a *function* which doesn't play very well with `+=1` -- since the latter works by side effect. If you really wanted to use the ternary operator, you could use:

```
(a,b) = (a+1,b)  if s[i] == '1' else (a,b+1)
```

If you are simply looking for a more pythonic solution, drop the loop and use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
counts = Counter(s)
a,b = counts['1'],counts['0']
```

Comment: yes both the methods are working...thanks John Coleman.

Answer (score 0):

```
a=0
s="1110000"
for i in range(len(s)):
  a += 1 if s[i]=='1' else 0

b= len(s) - a
```

Comment: yes this also works,thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using lambda function and then unpack your result from the list

```
sample= lambda x:  [x.count(i) for i in set(x)]
a,b = sample(s).  #Unpacking the result
print(a,b, end='\t')
```

output

```
3, 4
```

Option 2

```
new = lambda x,y: [sum([x + 1 for i in s if i =='1']),sum([y+1 for m in s if m != '1'])]
a,b = new(a,b)
print(a,b, end='\t')
```

output

```
3,4
```